# Dismissing keyBoard not working

Tags: iphone, ios

I followed the same procedure from Apple Documentation but i am facing some problem with dismissing the keyboard .

The code :

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:  (UITextField *) theTextField
 {

    if(theTextField == self.textField)
    {

       [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I know this question has been asked many times here , but i could not find an appropriate answer or an solution for this , so only i am posting this question.

Comment: Have you set your view controller as the delegate for the text field?  If not, control-drag from the text field to the controller, and select delegate.

Comment: Or if you created text field programmatically just set textField.delegate = YourController.

Comment: yes , i have done that .

Comment: @RafałAugustyniak: i don't understand, what you are trying to say.

Comment: Is `resignFirstResponder` being called, did you check?

Comment: it is not being called , what could i have missed ?

Comment: Are you sure you set the delegate for the textField?  Are you doing this programmatically or in the Storyboard?

Comment: Remove the if(theTextField == self.textField) condition there and test. If it works that way you should check what "self.textField" has.

Comment: @Mr.T: i am doing it in the storyboard

Comment: @srikanth: i tried , but no change

Comment: Try setting the delegate in the storyboard of the textfield to be the view controller.  You can right click on the textfield, and drag the little knob next to delegate onto your view controller.

Comment: @Mr.T: it already shows the connection between delegate and the view. I have done that earlier itself

Comment: The delegate is set to the view or the view controller?  That's different.

Comment: @Steve: I had not set the delegate properly , now it is working fine , thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your textfield's delegate is set to the view controller in the storyboard.  It can be done like this:

[image: setting delegate for your textfield]

Comment: Yea its working , i have set that to the FirstResponder by mistake. Thank You!